# How can i get chinese_prc_ci_ai for MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, collation, chinese-locale

I have a special need to create table with Collation "chinese_prc_ci_ai" but in my standard MySQL 2012 installation, all i can find is "big5", "gb2312" collations. Can you please help to guide me how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick James's answer has listed some collations you can use for Chinese. GB2312, GBK, GB18030 are national standards in PRC. GBK is most popular and GB18030 is latest standard. So why don't you try them, or you just want a collation whose name is 'chinese_prc_ci_ai'?

Comment: hi Xing, yes, actually that is the case. My client who locates in Shanghai somehow use that "chinese_prc_ci_ai" and ask me to replicate the environment. Have you heard of it?

Comment: @DatHuynh - MySQL and other vendors use different naming conventions for Collations.  I don't think any MySQL collations were named `..._ci_ai` before version 8.0, which is not yet GA.  Previously, `_ci` implied `_ci_ai` as opposed to `_ci_as`.

Comment: @DatHuynh Are your client using SQLserver? It has such collation name. If so, then it is another story - how to replicate data from SQLserver to MySQL.

Comment: hi Xing, you are right, my client is using SQL Server and it has a huge range of collation. Thanks for pointing this out, you save my day

Answer (score 0):

These are available in 8.0.0:

```
| big5_chinese_ci    | big5    |   1 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| gb18030_chinese_ci | gb18030 | 248 | Yes     | Yes      |       2 |
| gb2312_chinese_ci  | gb2312  |  24 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| gbk_chinese_ci     | gbk     |  28 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
```

plus utf8.

I am not familiar with "prc", so I can't say whether it is encoded the same as any of those.  Can you provide sample text -- a few characters, plus the `HEX()` of them; I'll see if they match.

The alternative is to write your own charset/collation.  There is a web page discussing that.

Or you could file a bug at http://bugs.mysql.com .  However it might not be available before 8.0.xx, maybe 8.1.

Comment: hi Rick, thanks for your response. As stated, somehow our customer used specifically "chinese_prc_ci_ai", he located in China actually. So if it is commonly accepted there is no prc then i think i have to ask them then. I accepted your answer as it is very clear.